# Can not run application directly from eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging

As you know that in eclipse, we have 2 modes to choose for implementing application: debug mode, and run mode ( By clicking right on project and choose whether Debug As or Run As.)

As usual, when I choose Run as, I will reinstall application and run it without waiting for debug.

Suddenly, I can not use this kind of Run as. It like Debug mode ( although I choose Run As).

Can everyone tell me why and how to solve this problem?

p/s: I can not run my app independently without my Laptop now.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show screenshot ?Your question is not clear ! Are you not able to get the Run As.. option or what ? Or do you get any kind of error in your console or logcat ?

Comment: Each time I choose " Run as", my device always appears "Waiting for debugger .... "( like in debug mode)

Comment: Make sure your application is already not in debug mode running.

Comment: Do you have open two eclipse instances ?

Comment: Of course, I choose "Run as", not "debug as".
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this kind of solution. And it worked.
Now i wanna share it.

What i do to fix it is:
_ restart computer
_ restart Eclipse
_ disconnect device and make connection to eclipse again.
_ kill adb server and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the adb server on the command line:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Eclipse will drop out its connection when you do kill-server and complain, but once you do start-server it should regain connectivity and be able to install/debug apps again.

Comment: It does not work. But it helps me some ways. 1 upvote. Thanks :)